# Не парсится rutor на хостинге

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема: на локалке все отлично, как только переношу на хостинг — сервер рутора перестает отвечать. То есть, например, если проверить через cURL:

```
function isUp($url) {
        if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            return false;
        }

        $curlInit = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
        curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
        curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
        curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

        $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

        curl_close($curlInit);

        if($response) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

то, возвращает FALSE. Далее, если убрать проверку, то просто ничего не выводит.

```
$page_content = file_get_contents('http://rutor.org/');
$html = phpQuery::newDocument($page_content);       
foreach($html->find('#index .tum, .gai') as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key]['date'] = pq($value)->find('td:eq(0)')->text();
}
```

Пробовал через cURL, подменять реферера,  ставить USER_AGENT, ничего не помогает.

В чем может заключаться данная проблема? Повторюсь, на локалке все прекрасно работает. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Политика безопасности сервера, на котором расположен хостинг. Вы уже разговаривали со службой поддержки вашего хостинга?

Если у вас на локальной машине все хорошо, то и у нас все будет хорошо... И с локальных машин и с хостингов без ограничений на curl, чем мы вам поможем? Вы ждете фразу: "У нас все работает. Руки просто правильно надо заточить."?

---

Добавьте в начало скрипта:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Загляните в логи сервера, если доступны.
Воспользуйтесь другими средствами отладки.

Что конкретно и в какой строке не отрабатывает, вы можете указать?

Comment: @LTKN, Все, разобрался, спасибо. Ошибка была и правда с моей стороны. За подсказку благодарю!

Comment: @evansive, вы уж меня извините, если немного резок. В последнее время складывается плохая тенденция - отсутствие внятной формулировки вопроса. Вроде: "вот код, что в нем не так? раньше работал." 
Я из собственной практики очень хорошо понял, что 80% ответа - это хорошо заданный вопрос. А если разжевываешь вопрос далекому от проекта человеку, иногда и договорить не успеваешь, как понимаешь свою ошибку. 
Удачи на страницах кода. Не забывайте, что всецело опираться на чужой контент не стоит, вдруг хозяевам в голову взбредет дизайн поменять или пути к страницам...

Answer (score 1):

перед

```
curl_close($curlInit);
```

напишите:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(curl_getinfo($curlInit), 1).'</pre>';
```

ну или выведите куда-то в лог.

Comment: @shurik, вот такое выводит:

http://pastebin.com/JHdQ3SVL

Кстати, тех. поддержка ответила, что со своей стороны не ограничивает доступ.